# Как остановить программу до тех пор, пока я не закрою Notepad с текстом?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, notepad++

После создания формы в PyQt открываю файл с помощью

```
file=os.startfile('file name')
```

или

```
webbrowser.open('file name').
```

Поскольку программа продолжает работать, файл открывается позади формы, что очень раздражает. Можно ли сделать Блокнот всегда активным окном (до закрытия) или остановить программу, пока не сделаю изменения в файле?

Comment: You need to translate your question into Russian, or move your question here [en.stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Моя задача просто открыть текстовый файл( не виджет) с помощью Notepad в теле программы и редактировать его, чтобы он не уходил на задний план.

Comment: @GeorgeZharik в сам вопрос поместите информацию необходимую для ответа. Нажмите [edit]. Какой у вас вопрос? Как фокус передать  внешнему приложению, которое файл открывает? Как его или свой z-order поменять?  Или как узнать когда это приложение перестало файл редактировать (сложно в общем случае—для конкретной программы возможны обходные решения)?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что нужен аналог [`Process.WaitForExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8(v=vs.110).aspx) в питоне?

Comment: WaitForExit (`QProcess.finished` в данном случае) не работает для программ, которые используют быстрый launcher, который открывает файл и сразу завершается, а файл продолжает быть открытым в серверном процессе (я не знаю, относится ли notepad++ к числу таких программ). Я вижу три вопроса как минимум: 1- как приложение с документом выше всех сделать (z-order, фокус) 2- как определить, когда редактирование файла завершено 3- как "остановить"/запустить заново по событию (свернуть/развернуть GUI?)

Answer (score 0):

**Вот скрипт если я правильно понял о чём речь**

```
import subprocess
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.resize(250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Example')

        self.button = QPushButton(self)
        self.button.setText('Открыть файл')
        self.button.clicked.connect(lambda:self._open(self.button))

        self.show()

    def _open(self, button):
        p = subprocess.Popen('notepad txt.txt')



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: кто поставил - и за что ?